# Modify osssearchresults.aspx page of WSS

Tags: sharepoint

We have an application where we modify the search core resuult web part XSLT of MOSS search result page (Results.aspx) to call some custom javascripts . Is it possible to do the same for the application level page of WSS i.e osssearchresults.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the search results page in a WSS installation, you need to customize your masterpage a bit to change that behavior.

it defaults to:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
```

but you can render some javascript under the control to fix the link for you (jQuery sample):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ms-searchform a[@id $= '_go']").attr("href", "#").click(function() { 
    // redirect to new page, getting the selected scope and keyword 
    });
</script>
```

the selector gets "the **a** element under the **.ms-searchform** class that ends with _go
in its **id** attribute". to get the scope and keyword, its a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own (just copy the osssearchresults.aspx to the site collection and edit it) and in the site settings change the url of the search results page.