# Customizing Sharepoint Search Box

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss

I followed [some](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/01/10/changing-the-smallsearchinputbox-delegate-control/) [tutorial](http://clintcherry.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEC0DCBC460E45B9!421.entry) to change the way Sharepoint Search Box is shown on screen.

My first problem is, after modifying the `SearchArea.xml` file, is there a way to force the reload? The frequency of reload seems very random.

Bonus question: is it the best way to do it?
It's the easiest I've found, but having to change the file on the client's production server when the project is deployed doesn't seems very optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you need to reactivate the feature to have it instally reload, check [this link in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442691.aspx)

The second question, I just answered in another post, [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866223/modify-osssearchresults-aspx-page-of-wss/1866864#1866864)

Answer (score 0):

Its very straight forward. All you have to do is create your custom CSS file and have it override the default styles from the corev15.css file.

The class for the Search inpubt Box is .ms-srch-sb

And you can use your custom styles something like:

```
.ms-srch-sb>input {
/* your custom css style*/
}
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers